# Firebase Cloud functions: ECONNREFUSED

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying the Optimizing Networking of firebase cloud functions like [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/networking) with Typescript

```js
const http = require('http');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const agent = new http.Agent({keepAlive: true});

export const getXXX = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const req = http.request({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 443,
        path: '',
        method: 'GET',
        agent: agent,
    }, res => {
        let rawData = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', chunk => { rawData += chunk; });
        res.on('end', () => {
            response.status(200).send(`Data: ${rawData}`);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', e => {
        response.status(500).send(`Error: ${e.message}`);
    });
    req.end();
});
```

but I keep getting

> error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

I am not very familiar with TypeScript and js so please help me.

Another question when is res.on 'Data' gets triggered ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be trying to access an external service instead of localhost on 443 (TLS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access anything on "localhost" (127.0.0.1) in Cloud Functions.  I suspect that you meant to put a different host in there, and ensure that your project is on the Blaze plan to enable outgoing connections to services not fully controlled by Google.

Comment: Please review the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/56627026/4782247

Comment: Is this also true for accessing localhost from a localhost cloud function? i.e. in the local emulator suite, can I access local cloud storage data from a locally-running cloud function?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I need to be on a paid plan in order to make external HTTP requests from inside my function.

Comment: That's what I was saying in my answer about being on the Blaze plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Cloud Functions on localhost. All you need to do is run a local emulator of the Cloud services. Which Google has provided! It's a really awesome tool and a great setup!

**Follow these steps for the Firebase tool suite:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

**Follow these steps for the Cloud tool suite:** https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator

They are pretty much similar.

You do not need Blaze plan, you can use the "pay as you go" plan, which includes the free tier quota. "Free usage from Spark plan included*" https://firebase.google.com/pricing